# Failed to add global permission to user Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I tried to add user global permissions to a cluster, but fail to add, received the following error message:

```
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "rancherauth.cattle.io": Post "https://rancher-webhook.cattle-system.svc:443/v1/webhook/validation?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.X.X.X: connect: connection refused
```

I found nothing about this.

Thanks.